# For Loop Error in string

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I'm trying to do a for loop in a string. This is what I have:

```
slideContainer.append('<div>' + for( i=0; i<=slideCount-1; i++ ){'<a>' + (i+1) + '</a>'} + '</div>');
```

What I want is for it to end up like this:

```
<div>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
  <a>4</a>
  <a>5</a>
</div>
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

It's referring to the one next to 'for'. What's going on?

Comment: Your code is illegal. That's what's going on. You can't do it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is illegal. Instead use a for loop to concatenate string and the add it to div

```
var str = "";
for (i = 0; i <= slideCount - 1; i++) {
    str += '<a>' + (i + 1) + '</a>';
}
slideContainer.append('<div>' + str + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 3):

In short -- `for` is instruction (statement), not an expression which returns value.

Usually we write instruction as `for ()` while expression (like function) are written as `fan()` -- space before `(` means that this is not expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
function returnSlideNum(slideCount)
{
var _ret = "";
for( i=0; i<=slideCount-1; i++ ){_ret+='<a>' + (i+1) + '</a>';}
return _ret;
}

slideContainer.append('<div>' + returnSlideNum(slideCount) + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. You could try something like this:

```
slideContainer.append('<div>' + 
(function() { 
    var str = "";
    for(var i=0; i<=slideCount-1; i++ ){ 
        str += '<a>' + (i+1) + '</a>'
    } 
    return str;
})()
+ '</div>');
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94ufr/1/)

This wraps your `for` loop in an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) which, as the name suggests, is an expression and therefore valid. But that's pretty ugly. Better would be to have `append` inside your loop:

```
var aDiv = $("div");
for (var i=0; i < slideCount; i++) {
    aDiv.append('<a>' + (i+1) + '</a>');
}
slideCountainer.append(aDiv);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94ufr/)